# Context Menu Destructive Actions, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I'm trying to add a delete action in a context menu, however it just gets displayed as the default black color. The Photos app uses a red color for its delete action as well. I've seen in some spaces online that this is not a functionality currently provided of `contextMenu`, however I have also seen it used in third party apps in the wild [here](https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1245789905609011202?s=20). Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Also, looking on Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/contextmenu) for `contextMenu` it says that they have been deprecated for everything except for macOS. I find it strange that they deprecated it just one year after introducing it. Was this replaced by another component that I should be using?

```
var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(photos) { photo in
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: photo.imageData!)!)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                        .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                            Button(action: {
                                deletePhoto(selectedPhoto: photo)
                            }) {
                                Label("Remove", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Albums"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingImagePicker = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                }
            )
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with different things: fg, bg, accent etc but to no avail. I'm guessing "not possible" at the moment.

ps ContextMenu is deprecated, but not .contextMenu
You're doing it right.

This is the non-deprecated one. The other one doesn't use a ViewBuilder

```
public func contextMenu<MenuItems>(@ViewBuilder menuItems: () -> MenuItems) -> some View where MenuItems : View
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the info on `.contextMenu` not being deprecated. Pretty confusing the naming of them, makes it hard to differentiate like that if you don't know that there's two.